# Ruby 2.3.1 is not compiling under Arch Linux

Tags: ruby, linux, build, rvm, archlinux

I've got a project using the following specification at `Gemfile`:

```
ruby '2.3.1', :engine => 'jruby', :engine_version => 'jruby-9.1.7.0'
```

and this was working fine under my old Debian 8.1 installation. But I decided to test Arch Linux and now I'm getting an error when I run

```
$ rvm install 2.3.1
```

**The Error:**

> Segmentation fault (core file generated)

[image]

I've never faced an error like this and got no ideas about how to solve it. Any suggestions?

**EDIT** => As required, I posted all `make.log` file as a Github Gist. This is the [link](https://gist.github.com/EdDeAlmeidaJr/4c35d4c219adf7a23d41c2b978d359f9) to it.

Comment: Can you retake the screenshot in English? Or post the error it is giving you in English? As it stands, it may take some time for your question to be answered since most users on SO will have to type out your error and have it translated.

Comment: Sorry... I'm using pt_BR.UTF-8 as locale and then it generated one sentence in Portuguese, indeed.

Comment: "Falha de segmentação (arquivo core criado)" means "Segmentation fault (core file generated)".

Comment: No problem, it just happened to be one of the more important lines :). Also you may want to paste a bit more of your `make.log` file. It looks like the stracktrace may start further up than the last 15 lines it provided.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, @Charles. I haven't even noticed the Portuguese sentence in the middle of it. I speak both languages and sometimes don't even notice when I change from one to the other.

Comment: I posted the `make.log` file as a Githug Gist, @Charles.

Comment: So after looking online for a bit, it looks like this is going to be a fun one. It looks like you may have to make a bug report for ruby [bugs.ruby-lang.org](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org). [This bug report](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/12118) _may_ be what you're looking for since it looks pretty similar, there are patches posted on it. If you want to fix it yourself, it looks like [Fixing a Segfault in Ruby Apps](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-segfault) would be a good read.

Comment: Yes, same conclusion here. No obvious path to solve this and the last thing I need now is to debug a segfault like that in the middle of an important project. Thanks for the links. I'll take a look and post a issue at RVM Github page.